# Stored Procedures in EF4.4

Tags: sql-server-2008, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

We have had to downgrade a project which used EF5, to EF4, and are battling to get a stored procedure into the EF model.

The procedure returns a table:

```
  -- A table to hold the results
  DECLARE @Result TABLE
  (
      ActionType    CHAR(1),
      ChangedBy     VARCHAR(50),
      ChangedDate   DATETIME,
      FieldName     VARCHAR(150),
      OriginalValue VARCHAR(100),
      NewValue VARCHAR(100),
      ForeignKeyName VARCHAR(50),
      ForeignKeyValue VARCHAR(15)
  )
```

and then adds records, and returns:

```
  -- Return the result
  SELECT * FROM @Result
```

However, adding a proc seems very different. The stored procedures are not showing up in our Entity Framework context.

So we follow the example shown here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx

However, we select the return type as 'Complex', but when we click 'Get Column Information', we're greeted with the following error:

> An exception of type
>   “Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.EnumeratorException” occurred
>   while attempting to get columns information. The exception message is:
>   ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The
>   connection’s current state is closed. The inner exception caught was
>   of type ‘System.InvalidOperationException’, with this error message:
>   ‘ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The
>   connection’s current state is closed.’.

Can anyone assist with this error, or maybe explain a better way to reference stored procedures in EF4.4?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Don't use SELECT *!

```
-- Return the result
  SELECT       
      ActionType,
      ChangedBy,
      ChangedDate,
      FieldName,
      OriginalValue,
      NewValue,
      ForeignKeyName,
      ForeignKeyValue
  FROM @Result
```

Comment: +1 *don't use `SELECT *`* is **always** good advice in a production system!

Comment: Indeed. I broke the rule. But hopefully my mistake will help others.